# Can not compile simple mysql program

Tags: mysql, c, compiler-construction

cblog.c:

```
#include "html.h"
#include "config.h"
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
//#include <my_global.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
        MYSQL *conn;
        MYSQL_RES *res;
        MYSQL_ROW row;

        conn = mysql_init(NULL);

        // Connect to database
        if (!msyql_real_connect(conn, server, username, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                exit(1);
        }

        // Query the DB
        if (mysql_query(conn, "show tables")) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
                exit(1);
        }
        res = mysql_use_result(conn);

        htmlf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
        while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
                htmlf("%s \n", row[0]);

        mysql_free_result(res);
        mysql_close(conn);

        html("Hello World!");
        return 0;
}
```

Makefile:

```
all:
#       gcc -Wall cblog.c html.c -o cblog `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
#       gcc -Wall cblog.c html.c -L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient -o cblog
        gcc cblog.c html.c -Wall $(shell mysql_config --cflags) -o cblog $(shell mysql_config --libs)
test: all
        ./cblog
```

Output:

```
ttouch cblog$ make
gcc cblog.c html.c -g -Wall -I/usr/include/mysql -fPIC -pipe -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -fno-strict-aliasing -DBIG_JOINS=1 -fomit-frame-pointer -g -DNDEBUG -o cblog -L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
cblog.c: In function ‘main’:
cblog.c:16:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘msyql_real_connect’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  if (!msyql_real_connect(conn, server, username, password, database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
  ^
/tmp/ccs1WQsi.o: In function `main':
/media/files/Lab/cblog/cblog.c:16: undefined reference to `msyql_real_connect'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I know this question has been answered over a thousand times, I've searched all over the internet, I've tested putting `mysql_config` at the beginning or at the end. I know that it gives the right paths (checked)

`ls /usr/lib/ | grep mysql`:

```
libmysqlclient.a
libmysqlclient_r.a
libmysqlclient_r.so
libmysqlclient_r.so.18
libmysqlclient_r.so.18.0.0
libmysqlclient.so
libmysqlclient.so.18
libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0
libmysqld.a
libmysqld.so
libmysqld.so.18
libmysqlservices.a
mysql
tdbcmysql1.0.0
```

`ls /usr/include/mysql | grep mysql`:

```
mysql_com.h
mysqld_ername.h
mysqld_error.h
mysql_embed.h
mysql.h
mysql_time.h
mysql_version.h
```

Sorry for the noobish question, but I've been banging my head for about 4-5 hours

Comment: If you look in the MYSQL header files do you see a definition for `msyql_real_connect()`? If you do, you could try editing the file... Put a `#error` directive in there to make sure that it is the file you're looking at that is getting included... you could also try using the `nm` command to look at the symbols defined in the library file to check that the symbol exists there. If it does, try temporarily renaming the file to make sure it is the one being linked against... hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you man. It turned out it's just a typo, but you gave useful info (I'm a noob) for feature debugging. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the function name, `msyql_real_connect` should be `mysql_real_connect`